# couldn't get Application context

Tags: unit-testing, spring-boot, vaadin, junit4

I am writing vaadin test bench (5.0.2) UI test cases with spring boot application and I am writing as `@RunWith(Junit4.class)` as by writing `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` loads something behind the hood and it requires the spring application pre run but I want to test in different environment, which is already up and just one can run the test case and get the Application context from the configuration without running the project is it possible?

I have tried manier things like `@Dirtiescontext` `@SpringRunner` etc.But for `@RunWith(Junit4.class)` no annotations work at the class level so couldn't able to get the Application Context.

```
@WebAppConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = UIConfiguration.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:testData/testdata.properties")
public abstract class BaseTestCase extends TestBenchTestCase {
    //some basic configurations for loading Drivers.
}
```

I need a configuration for Vaadin based Spring boot project which can provide me Application Context without running anything behind the hood as the @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) loads the entire thing.

Comment: facing same issue with vaadin test bench and spring boot application. can not access any bean from context (like UIConfiguration). any solution surely helps.